# Get file with particular extension and check the size of the file

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, c#-3.0

I am trying to go into a folder and look for files with extension .abc, these files will come and go in this folder but what i want to know is if this file exists and size of the file is greater than 50kb then i should be notified. I have this code:

```
if(File.Exists(@"c:\home\myfolder\*.abc"))
{

}
```

I dont think putting an * will get me files with extension .abc, does anyone know how i can achieve this and get the size of the file if it exists?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\home\myfolder", "*.abc");
if (files.Length > 0)
{
}
```

Comment: How can i check if file size is greater than 50kb?

Comment: `if (new System.IO.FileInfo(files[0]).Length > 50 * 1024)`